# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsMatch

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have the following query:

```
result.AddRange((from app in db.AllJobModel where Regex.IsMatch(app.JobTitle, "\b" + listjobs + "\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) && Regex.IsMatch(app.locationName, "\b" + searchLocation + "\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) select app).ToList());
```

The error I got is as follows:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsMatch(System.String, System.String, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Not all databse engines support regular expressions. Even for those that do, I don't believe any LINQ-to-SQL providers know how to properly translate them into SQL. Your only option is going to be client-side evaluation which you can achieve with `AsEnumerable`.

```
result.AddRange((
    from app in db.AllJobModel.AsEnumerable() 
    where Regex.IsMatch(app.JobTitle, "\b" + listjobs + "\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) && 
          Regex.IsMatch(app.locationName, "\b" + searchLocation + "\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) 
    select app
));
```

Note that the implication here is that all records will be returned from the database and the filtering will be performed in memory.

Depending on your data, you *might* be able to get by using the equivalent of `Like '% XYZ %'` (note the spaces before and after). This would at least translate into SQL and run entirely at the server rather than in-memory:

```
result.AddRange((
    from app in db.AllJobModel.AsEnumerable() 
    where app.JobTitle.Contains(" " + listjobs + "  ") && 
          app.locationName.Contains(" " + searchLocation + " ") 
    select app
));
```

Or you could combine `Contains`, `StartsWith` and `EndsWith` (and a space) which should give you something a bit closer:

```
result.AddRange((
    from app in db.AllJobModel.AsEnumerable() 
    where (app.JobTitle.Contains(" " + listjobs + "  ") || app.JobTitle.StartsWith(listjobs + " ") || app.JobTitle.EndsWith(" " + listjobs)) && 
          (app.locationName.Contains(" " + searchLocation + " ") || app.locationName.StartsWith(searchLocation + " ") || app.locationName.EndsWith(" " + searchLocation)) 
    select app
));
```

Unfortunately you're not going to be able to match your regex *exactly* but you should be able to come close.

Answer (score -1):

try :

```
result.AddRange((from app in db.AllJobModel where app.JobTitle.Contains("\b" + listjobs + "\b") && app.locationName.Contains("\b" + searchLocation + "\b") select app).ToList());
```

Comment: this will not compile

Comment: This looks for the literal string "\b" + the rest, which doesn't make sense.